# Chronic tonsillitis after tonsillectomy

Tags: tonsil-tonsillectomy, antiseptics

A topic is rather strange right? Tonsillitis is an inflammatory condition of tonsils and there is pretty much nothing after the conventional tonsillectomy. Nevertheless this is what it seems to look like.

The case. My gf, 22, had been suffering from chronic tonsillitis since childhood. Lacune samples always showed presence of Streptococcus Aureus. Antiseptic treatment by a wide range of local antiseptics (including the Chlorophyllipt, and rather uncommon Brilliant Green) in best cases gave temporary relief, in most cases there was no effect.

A year ago she underwent Tonsillectomy without any complications, however the pain remained. Moreover, something similar to tonsillar lacunae started to form where the tonsils used to be (abscess?).

I'm no medic, but considering inefficiency of antiseptics, I strongly suspect an autoimmune reaction. To support this idea, she had Pityriasis rosea in anamnesis a couple of years earlier which had been symptomatically treated with local steroids.

We had visited lots and lots of doctors. The case seems to be unconventional and nobody seems to care so this is my desperate attempt to request for fresh opinion on what should we do next.